# How to move first list item to the end?

Tags: clojure

For given list:

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

I'd like to get as output:

```
(2 3 4 1)
```

Code I came up with looks like this:

```
(flatten (cons (rest l) (list (first l))))
```

However my feeling is, that I overcomplicated this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Use a vector instead. Then conj does the right thing.

Comment: good instinct about flatten. flatten is usually the wrong thing because it ruins the structure of the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `flatten` a `cons`, just use `concat`.
Here is [an example](http://langref.org/clojure/lists/modification/rotate):

```
(let [fruit ["apple" "orange" "grapes" "bananas"]]
  (concat (rest fruit) [(first fruit)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Developing @stonemetal's hint, we can quickly and lazily rotate a vector thus:

```
(defn rotate [v n]
  (let [cv (count v), n (mod n cv)]
    (concat (subvec v n cv) (subvec v 0 n))))
```

It works in either direction:

```
(map #(rotate (vec (range 5)) %) (range -2 8))
;((3 4 0 1 2)
; (4 0 1 2 3)
; (0 1 2 3 4)
; (1 2 3 4 0)
; (2 3 4 0 1)
; (3 4 0 1 2)
; ...
; (2 3 4 0 1))
```

---

So to rotate the first in a sequence to the end:

```
(rotate (vec (range 1 5)) 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **destructuring** (either on the function arguments or in a let binding).

```
(let [[h & tail] '(1 2 3 4)]
  (concat tail (list h)))  ;=> (1 2 3 4)
```